# reset bios Lenovo X1 Carbon 20A7: error 0199

Tags: laptop, bios, passwords, lenovo-laptop, reset

I have a Lenovo X1 Carbon model 20A7. Windows 10.

I have lost the super user password for bios long time ago.

Lenovo System Update tool tried to install a newer version of bios today and I entered the password incorrectly 3 times and now I cannot use the machine.

When it starts it gives me the following error:

> 0199: System Security - Security password retry count exceeded.

When I press F1 to go to bios it asks me for figure print. It recognizes my finger print, but then again asks for password. If i skip the fiber print step out still asks for password.

I have disconnected the coin cell battery (Lenovo Maintenance Manual, section 1110). No success. Just additional error that

> 0271: Real Time Clock Error - Check Date and Time settings.

Which I think means I have correctly discounted the bios battery, but 0199 is still there.

I still remember my Windows 10 Pro password and finger print reader still recognized my finger print.

Is there a way to bypass this prompt?

Is there a way to reset the bios super user password? (without replacing the motherboard)

I have seen some videos that day sorry circuit two pins of EPROM chip, I tried that but it doesn't seem to work.

I also saw some video about removing the EPROM and overwriting the bios with some chip programming hardware (but I don't have the hardware and not sure it is plausible).

I am not sure if I enabled bitlocker hard disk encryption, this is laptop from many years ago. My guess is that I didn't, but not completely sure.

I am stuck. Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Most modern laptops make it virtually impossible to do what you’re attempting to do. If your able to login into Windows you should verify if BitLocker is enabled or disabled. Your probably looking at replacing the EPROM itself but that requires soldering skills and the hardware to program the EPROM.

Comment: (1) After taking out the CMOS battery, did you wait half an hour before putting it back in? (2) Do you get a BIOS message of  "System Disabled" with a numeric code? This could be used. (3) See more info [here](https://www.cocosenor.com/articles/computer/3-ways-to-unlock-bios-password-on-lenovo-thinkpad-laptop.html).